# opencv poor precision in object detection

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

I am trying to use opencv to detect small triangles in legal documents.  These triangles indicate a formalities error that requires correction.  Thus it is important to have good accuracy and avoid false positives for files with no triangles and REALLY avoid false negatives.

I have managed to duplicate the problem with some contrived files.

First, the basic document (trimmed for size)

[image]

And this is the resulting output.

[image]

The resulting output is created with this python code.   I have experimented with

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.05 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
```

and 0.05 seems to give the best results.  Lower values detect nothing, higher values increase the false positives.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Reading image
img2 = cv2.imread('/home/jmf/triangles/input.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.imread('/home/jmf/triangles/input.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

_,threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255,
                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


contours,uu_=cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours :
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,
                            0.05 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)


    if(len(approx) == 3):
        cv2.drawContours(img2, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)

cv2.imwrite("/home/jmf/triangles/output.jpeg", img2)
```

Comment: when using the findCountours function, it will look for any shape with the variables you defined, so it has a high rate of false positives. I suggest you using template matching if the triangle has always the same size and shape

Comment: some pre proccesing could help too, if the triangle is always on the same area on the document you could restrict the area you are searching

Comment: I've been trying pattern matching with no success. It tends to match capital "A"'s.  I basically cut that small triangle out of one of the files and used it as the template.  Unfortunately, the triangles can appear anywhere.

Comment: try playing with some erosion, dilation and see if it helps. CannyEdge detection could help too

Comment: are the triangles of fixed size, shape and orientation, or do they differ stronger, e.g. because they are handwritten or sth.? You could use a small neural network with a lot of training data. Or you should define well what you want to detect (triangle contour, filled, black, apart from the text?) and use every detail of that definition in your hand crafted algorithm.

Comment: @Micka same size and color and shape, plus orientation but position an vary.

Comment: I was trying to run `pytesseract` whitelisting only those triangle characters like ▲, but I couldn't get it working. Maybe, someone with more experience might have a look at this route - or can tell, if it won't work with standard `pytesseract`. Manually training the engine would be same as Micka mentioned using a small, custom NN.